# How can I get the courseWorkId when using the Classroom Share button

Tags: javascript, google-classroom

I am using the [Classroom Share Button](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton) to let users create assignments with  resources from my Website on Google Classroom.

Is it possible to retrieve the courseId and the courseWorkId of the newly created assignment?
I need this info to be able to store it on my website and reuse it later.

I already tried to use the callback "onsharecomplete", but it does not seem to get the required info as parameter. I also could not find any documentation about the arguments of this method.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="google-classroom-div">
  <div className="g-sharetoclassroom" data-size="32" data-url="https://www.example.com" data-onsharecomplete="onShareComplete"></div>
</div>
```

And the javascript to render the button and handle the callback looks like this:

```
gapi.sharetoclassroom.go("google-classroom-div");
window.onShareComplete = (arg1, arg2) => {
  console.log(arg1); // is undefined
  console.log(arg2); // contains some weird data
};
```

I know that there is another way to create assignments by using the Classroom API, i.e. the REST Resource [v1.courses.courseWork.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork) but then I would have to create the UI for choosing the course and posting the assignment on my own which I would like to avoid.

Comment: That would be the closest workaround you can do. Using the Rest API, you can have the freedom to create a complex function that you can customize. You can follow the quickstart sample for [javascript](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js) to be guided on how to a simple browser application that makes requests to the Classroom API. Hope this helps.